# Best method for creating and storing csrf token for oauth requests in nodejs

Tags: node.js, next.js, oauth-2.0, oauth, csrf

I have recently been tasked with creating a custom oauth login and signup flow. So I was curious what is the best way to go about generating and storing csrf tokens for oauth requests. I have read several articles on this like this one from [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/attack-protection/state-parameters). They state that a csrf token (random string) should be placed in the of the request to the oauth provider then stored locally. Then when the callback url is hit you can check the token in the state with the one you stored locally to see whether the request is valid.

So then I read the following article from [Bright Sec](https://brightsec.com/blog/csrf-token/). It states that

> Just like session tokens in general, CSRF tokens should contain significant entropy and be strongly unpredictable.
>
> You can achieve this by using a cryptographic strength pseudo-random number generator (PRNG), seeded with the timestamp when it was created and a static secret.

So this says that they should be a little more than just a random string like the auth0 article. So something like a uuid (which was my initial thought) may not really meet the standards for a good csrf token.

Also most of these articles that I have come across have been for submitting forms.

**So my question is what is the best way to create a csrf token in nodejs and where should I store it locally when authenticating to providers like Google and Facebook?**

**My current understanding of what should happen.**

1. User starts an authentication request and at this point you create a csrf token (still not sure best method for doing this) and save it locally (Maybe to a session?).
2. Send this token to the oauth provider in the state param
3. When the oauth provider responds back to your callback url they will send that token back to you in the state param and you should compare the 2 to make sure the request is authentic.

There are crsf libraries for nodejs. Mostly Express middleware but I'm not really sure that would apply to oauth requests. I have been trying to comb through passportjs and next-auth to see what their methods are but I think it is leaving me more confused than anything. It seems like Next Auth stores the csrf token as a cookie in the browser as shown in the image below:

[image: Cookie image]

So I can only assume from this the the csrf token is basically just to make sure that if somebody intercepts the request from the oauth provider back to the origins callback url they cannot use it from their browser. So the csrf token is just to make sure that the the request hitting the callback url was initiated from the same browser that it started. Correct?

Anyway any help here would be appreciated on how to create the token and where should I store it?

Comment: You wouldn't really do this in just Node, there's going to be some HTTP layer involved like Express or whatever you prefer. Most of these have some kind of CSRF middleware you just bolt in.

Comment: "I have recently been tasked with creating a custom oauth login and signup flow." Any reason you can't use something that already exists like [Passport](https://www.passportjs.org)?

Comment: Well i am using nextjs without express. So no express middleware and the actual implementation of oauth is not that difficult I just am not really sure about the best method to creating/ storing the token. Next Auth is a pain and it just automatically signs up users when they try to log in. So a custom implementation is much easier than dealing with a library. I just need to know how to go about creating/storing this token.

Comment: "the actual implementation of oauth is not that difficult" seems suspect. There's a lot of wild variation here, and the projects that implement it are surprisingly complex. The first 80% of the implementation is always easy. It's the remaining 800% that's really hard.

Comment: Why not [NextAuth](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/oauth) then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its beneficial to understand how a possible attack can happen in order to understand how CSRF can potentially help.

> User starts an authentication request and at this point you create a csrf token (still not sure best method for doing this) and save it locally (Maybe to a session?).
> Send this token to the oauth provider in the state param
> When the oauth provider responds back to your callback url they will send that token back to you in the state param and you should compare the 2 to make sure the request is authentic.

Yes, you are correct here. If there was no CSRF here, a malicious actor could just capture the URL and get a third party to visit that url instead, they will be able to access their account.

You can prevent this by creating a randomised state value using something that is unguessable by the malicious actor eg a session key tagged to userId.

There is no standardised way of storing this key. You could also a use TOTP based solution which you can use to invalidate token if it takes too long for the oauth2 flow to return. This allows you to just store the temporary secret used to generate the key tagged to some user identifier which you can just store serverside in a redis cache. This way during the validation step you just need to recreate the CSRF based on the stored temp key and validate.

So now you initiate your normal oauth2 flow as you mentioned and then compare the token for validation.

I hope this helps and other experts could chime in. I am writing this on mobile so pardon any formatting issues.

Comment: Awesome so I should be good with just storing the token in a session then right? It looks like that's where Next Auth stores their token and it expires with the session. I also picked through Next Auths code and it looks like they are just using a randomly generated 32 character string hashed with a secret. So ill probably just do something like that.

Comment: I would still suggest you use a recognised library to generate your temporary secret and not implement your own hashing function. I think most TOTP libraries come with a helper function to generate a hash

Comment: Ok session should be good for storage then right? Unless there is something I'm missing.

Comment: Yeah so long as you take adequate steps to prevent XSS attacks. If you are using TOTP I would recommend storing it somewhere serverside.  
I would also reccomend you to run your setup through a security expert.